# Ruby on Rails searching through ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my application I have search that find proper cars. It works properly. But now I want to use ajax. My search is based on form_object:

```
class SearchForm
  include Virtus.model
  include ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  attribute :car_class, String, default: "A"
  attribute :handover_location, Integer
  attribute :return_location, Integer
  attribute :handover_date, DateTime,
    default: ->(form, attribute) { Time.current }
  attribute :return_date, DateTime,
    default: ->(form, attribute) { form.handover_date + 7.days }
  attribute :car_body_style, Integer
  attribute :car_fuel, Integer
  attribute :car_seats, Integer
  attribute :car_transmission, Integer
  attribute :car_brand, Integer

  def submit
    Car.search({
      handover_date: handover_date,
      return_date: return_date,
      handover_location: handover_location,
      return_location: return_location,
      car_class_id: car_class,
      car_body_style: car_body_style,
      car_fuel: car_fuel,
      car_seats: car_seats,
      car_transmission: car_transmission,
      car_brand: car_brand
    })
  end
end
```

I have controller "Cars" with action index which is responsible for searching proper cars:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :attributes_from_params
  skip_authorization_check

  def index
    @search_form = SearchForm.new(params[:search_form])
    @cars = Car.search(@search_form)
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def attributes_from_params
    @car_class = CarClass.where(id: params[:search_form][:car_class]).first.name
    @handover_location = "#{Location.where(id: params[:search_form][:handover_location]).first.name } 
      #{params[:search_form][:handover_date]}"
    @return_location = "#{Location.where(id: params[:search_form][:return_location]).first.name } 
      #{params[:search_form][:return_date]}"
    @handover_date = params[:search_form][:handover_date].to_date
    @return_date = params[:search_form][:return_date].to_date
    @days = @return_date - @handover_date
  end
end
```

My index views looks like this:

```
 #reservation.row
  = horizontal_simple_form_for @search_form, {url: cars_path, method: :get, remote: true} do |f|
    .basic_search
      = f.input :handover_location, label: I18n.t('.handover'), collection: Location.all.map{|hl| [hl.name, hl.id]}
      = f.input :handover_date, as: :string, label: false
      = f.input :return_location, label: I18n.t('.return') ,collection: Location.all.map{|rl| [rl.name, rl.id]}
      = f.input :return_date, as: :string, label: false
      = f.input :car_class, label: I18n.t('.car_class') ,collection: CarClass.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    #search-results.row
      #search-filters.col-md-3
        %h4.filter-header
          = t('search.car_type')
        .filter-content.car-type
          = f.input :car_body_style, as: :check_boxes, collection: CarBodyStyle.all.map{|x| ["#{x.name}", "#{x.id}"]}, label: false
        %h4.filter-header
          = t('search.seats')
        .filter-content.number-of-people
          .checkbox
            = f.input :car_seats, as: :check_boxes, collection: [["2", "2"], ["3-5", "5"], ["6+", "6"]], label: false
        %h4.filter-header
          = t('search.fuel')
        .filter-content
          = f.input :car_fuel, as: :check_boxes, collection: [["#{t('enumerize.car.fuel.petrol')}", "petrol"], ["#{t('enumerize.car.fuel.petrol_lpg')}", "petrol_lpg"], ["#{t('enumerize.car.fuel.diesel')}", "diesel"]], label: false
        %h4.filter-header
          = t('search.transmission')
        .filter-content
          = f.input :car_transmission, as: :check_boxes, collection: [["#{t('enumerize.car.transmission.manual')}", "manual"], ["#{t('enumerize.car.transmission.automatic')}", "automatic"], ["#{t('enumerize.car.transmission.semiautomatic')}", "semiautomatic"]], label: false
      #search-cars.col-md-9
        = render @cars

        %br/
      = f.submit t('home.search'), class: "btn btn-default pull-right"
```

and "_car" partial:

```
.single-car
  .row
    .car-img.col-sm-2.col-md-3.col-lg-4
      = image_tag image_path("portal/car-sample.jpg"), width: "140", height: "26"
    .car-info.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-6
      %h2= car.car_model
      %p.location
        = car.rental_company.name
        %br/
        = car.rental_company.correspondence_address.to_label if car.rental_company.correspondence_address
      .details
        %span.passengers
          = car.seats
        %span.doors
          = car.doors
        %span.air-conditioning
          = car_air_condition(car)
        %span.gearbox
          = car.transmission.try(:text)
        %span.fuel
          = car_fuel(car)
      .other-details
        = t('search.regulations')
        |
        = t('search.distance_limit')
        BRAK DANYCH
        = image_tag image_path("portal/mastercard.jpg"), width: "26", height: "15"
        = image_tag image_path("portal/visa.jpg"), width: "32", height: "10"
    .car-price.col-sm-3.col-md-2.col-lg-2
      %p.overall-price
        = number_to_currency(car.price_for_day(@handover_date, @return_date) * @days)
      %p.daily-price
        = t('search.for_day')
        = number_to_currency(car.price_for_day(@handover_date, @return_date))
      %p.deposit-price
        = t('search.caution')
        Brak Danych
        = hidden_field :test, "as"
        = link_to t('search.reservate'), new_reservation_path(search_form: params[:search_form], car: car.id), class: 'btn'
  %hr/
```

I've also created an index.js.erb file which looks like this:

```
$("#search-cars").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@cars)) %>");
```

This simple ajax search works properly but I must click chceckbox and then click submit button. I want to have checkboxes which are also submit buttons. Is there any way to do this thing? I don't have to much expierience with ajax so I will be very greatful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it in other way. I've add code that submits the form after checkbox click.

```
 $('#search-filters input[type=checkbox]').click ->
    $(this).closest("form").submit()
```

Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

We've done Ajax search before (you can check [here](http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk))

The way to do it is quite simple. I know you've fixed it, but I guess having more examples will give you some really nice ideas:

--

**Ajax**

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is very simple when you understand it

It basically makes an *asynchronous* request to your server through javascript, allowing you to render the response on the page. The way it works is to add to the [`http` protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) (which basically just responds to single requests made to the server). Ajax essentially gives you the ability to create a "no refresh" experience

---

**Example**

[image]

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
match 'search(/:search)', :to => 'products#search', :as => :search, via: [:get, :post]
```

--

**View** (we use `form_tag` - not `form object`)

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => :post, :id => "SearchForm" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'Search your favourite products or brands', :autocomplete => :off, :id => 'SearchSearch'  %> 
    <%= image_submit_tag('nav_bar/search.png', title: 'Search', class: 'search_submit', data: { "placement" => "bottom" }) %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def search      
    @products = Product.search(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js  { render :partial => "elements/livesearch", :locals => {:search => @products, :query => params[:search]} }
     format.html    { render :index }
    end
end
```

--

**JS**

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).ready( function() {

    var base_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

    $('#SearchSearch').searchbox({
        url: base_url + '/search/',
        param: 'search',
        dom_id: '#livesearch',
        loading_css: '#livesearch_loading'
    })      
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Make an AJAX call on checkbox change event.
2. Render partial containing the search results that you want to show on front-end from the controller.
3. Replace the search results in the front-end using javascript inside success function of AJAX request!

This should solve your problem! :)